# Wildfly listen on port 8080 and httpd on port 80 and redirect without port number 8080 on URL

Tags: apache, centos7

AWS CentOS 64b / HTTP / Wildfly 10 / PHPBB php forum / java project

**Scenario :**

My URL is : www.apisani.org

I have httpd listening on port 80

I have Wildfly listening on port 8080

**My needs :** I need to type in the browser : www.apisani.org and be redirected to wildfly - java application on port 8080 but dont want to show the port number in the URL.

I need to type in the browser : www.forum.apisani.org and be redirected to httpd on port 80 - phpbb forum website.

---

I know how to setup wildfly in standalone.xml and welcome-content to redirect www.apisani.org to www.apisani.org/app/indexapp.xhtl but the problem is given above on "My needs" section

[UPDATED BASED ON FISH REPLIES...]

We are almost there ! 
The `<virtualHost>` is working like a charm !

**:(** The ReWriteConde redirects to wildfly URL app instead of forum...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.forum\.apisani\.org$
RewriteRule (.*) http://apisani.org:80/phpBB3/$1 [P,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.apisani\.org$
RewriteRule (.*) http://apisani.org:80/phpBB3/$1 [P,L]

<VirtualHost *:80>
  Servername www.apisani.org
  ServerAlias apisani.org

  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass  / http://apisani.org:8080/app/index
  ProxyPassReverse / http://apisani.org:8080/app/index
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a rewrite and [P] for that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.apisani.org$
RewriteRule (.*) http://wildfly:8080/$1 [P,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.forum.apisani.org$
RewriteRule (.*) http://phpbb-forum-website:80/$1 [P,L]
```

$1 refers to (.*) --> the whole URI. If you want to pass that to your application. If not, just lose the brackets and $1

Let us know if that was what you were looking for. And if not, even more, so we can help furthermore ;)

---

**UPDATE**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?apisani\.org$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ apisani.org:8080/<path> [P,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?forum\.apisani\.org$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ apisani.org/<path> [P,L]
```

Comment: the RewriteRule with wildfly:8080 redirects to wildfly server application on port 80 but wildfly server application is not listening on port 80. its listening on 8080. So the app fails loading.

Comment: Why do you think (log-entry?) that wildfly:8080 got redirected to port 80? I mean, it is right in there: go for port 8080. And is Wildfly really listening on 8080? Is there any further component that is able of re-mapping ports, like a loadbalancer?

Comment: Wildfly is listening on port 8080 and its tested. Theres way to talk with you by chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139605/discussion-between-hello-fishy-and-al2x).

Comment: Sure. Hello Fishy, Your last update worked like a charm ! Ty